# How can I inject agents in a source block from an uploaded database table?

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to inject agents from a database into a specific source block. The database consists of 2 columns of "OrderType" & "OrderAmount". I wish to inject "OrderAmount" of agents of their corresponding "OrderType" into this source, while retaining the differentiation (I.E. by storing a parameter attribute ID of each entry/agent in the corresponding agenttype of the source block).
I have saved the entries from the database in collections and constructed a table as such (For both arrays; type = double):

```
double [][] ArrayCustomerOrders = new double [coll_CustomerOrderType.size()][2];
for (int i = 0; i < coll_CustomerOrderType.size(); i++) {
ArrayCustomerOrders[i][0] = coll_CustomerOrderType.get(i);
ArrayCustomerOrders[i][1] = coll_CustomerOrderAmount.get(i);
}
```

I tried playing around with the source block calls of inject() function in the same event as I constructed the order table in, but was unable to inject eligible arguments.
Does anyone have a suggestion on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you can simply replace the `Source` block with an `Enter` block (named "myEnterBlock"):

Create an empty agent population `pop_Orders` with an agent type that has 2 parameters `p_Type` and `p_Amount`.

In your for-loop code, when you have the current order type and amount, create such an agent and push it into the Enter block directly:
`myEnterBlock.take(add_pop_Orders(currentType, currentAmount))`

Comment: Hi, please always open new issues for "additional questions", this is how SOF works. Also, if this answer helped, please upvote it (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote )